# How to define Java transient attributes in Enterprise Architect?

Tags: java, transient, enterprise-architect

Background: I'm using Sparx Enterprise Architect 8.0. When I mark a member of a domain class as `transient`, the resulting generated code uses the `volatile` keyword instead of `transient`. This is correct according to [Enterprise Architect Java conventions](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/8.0/software_development/java_conventions.html).

How can I define *transient* attributes using EA and have the generated code to use the Java `transient` keyword for them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a tagged value on the attribute (not the class), named `transient` with value `true`.

This works in 9.1; unfortunately I don't have an 8.0 installation to try this on. You can check it yourself by looking at the relevant generation template: select Settings - Code Generation Templates, then pick Java in the language drop-down (top left). In the Templates list, find the one called "Attribute Declaration."

If there is a line starting with `%attTag:"transient"`, the above should work. If not, you can add it yourself if you know how (code generation templates are not a good area for experimentation), but I don't want to post Sparx-copyrighted material here.

Sadly, using tagged values on attributes means you can't see this property in diagrams or the project browser. That's just a fact of life, but it might be worth the bother to hassle Sparx about putting in some sort of way of showing attribute tags.

Comment: The template is aware of the transient tagged attribute in 8.0 too. Thanks a lot!